# Two custom cells layout in TableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableView on mainStoryboard with two custom cells.

I would like to set two more cells at different row. I was trying to find the answer but could not find out.

I have image and code added below.

[image]

[image]

```
   class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

        @IBOutlet var tblStoryList: UITableView!

        var array = PLIST.shared.mainArray



        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


        //spacing between header and cell
            self.tblStoryList.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 0, 0, 0)

          //delete separator of UITableView
        tblStoryList.separatorStyle = .none

        }
       func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.array.count + 1
        }



         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell
                cell.headerTitle.text = "First Stage"
                return cell
            }

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StoryTableviewCell", for: indexPath) as! StoryTableviewCell


            //making plist file
            let dict = self.array[indexPath.row - 1]
            let title = dict["title"] as! String
            let imageName = dict["image"] as! String
            let temp = dict["phrases"] as! [String:Any]
            let arr = temp["array"] as! [[String:Any]]
            let detail = "progress \(arr.count)/\(arr.count)"

            //property to plist file
            cell.imgIcon.image = UIImage.init(named: imageName)
            cell.lblTitle.text = title
            cell.lblSubtitle.text = detail

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none


            return cell
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your conditions for `HeaderCell` and use ternary operator to set `headerTitle`

```
if indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 3 || indexPath.row == 5 {
    let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell
    cell.headerTitle.text = indexPath.row == 0 ? "First Stage" : indexPath.row == 3 ? "Second Stage" : "Third Stage"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: When I implemented the code the custom cell replaces original cell. Do you have any idea to fix it?

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: I added the image. Custom cell that includes "Basic grammar3" and "Basic grammar5" are disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Stages as a row, use them as a section header. You can put custom view in header section.

**Main Idea :**
section-ize your row along with stages, put the cell's data in an array and add them in a dictionary with the section value as their key. To visualise your case the dictionary will look like following.

```
@{
     @"First Stage" : @[object_for_basic_grammar_1,
                        object_for_basic_grammar_2
                       ],
     @"Second Stage": @[object_for_basic_grammar3],
     ...
     ...
}
```

And Another array is needed to store the order of the dictionary keys, which will visualise to following

```
@[@"First Stage", @"Second Stage"
]
```

Now step by step follow the list:

1. Use [numberOfSections(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614860-numberofsections) for providing that how many stages here. return the count of the array which stores the sections.
2. Use [tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614931-tableview) for providing the number of rows in that section. get the section string object from the section list array declared later and search for the rows in the dictionary. You'll find a array of grammars here, return the count of that array.
3. Use [tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview) for providing the particular cell for that row as you've done for the grammar's cell.
4. Use [tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614855-tableview) for providing the height for the section header.
5. Now implement [tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview) and return the view for specifying the section view, which in your case is the stages.

hope it helps you, best of luck.